# Extracting values frm a number in C

Tags: c, date, bit-shift

I have the following assignment:

> Considering that the 32 bits on an unsigned integer represent a date
>   like this:
>   **Bits 0 to 7 are the day
>
>   Bits 8 to 23 are the year
>
>   Bits 24 to 31 are the month**
>   Implement the function unsigned ***int
>   greater_date(unsigned int date1, unsigned int date2)*** that returns the
>   greater of the two dates passed as parameters.

How can I extract the day, year and month using shifts of bits?

I developed this:

```
n = 16;
year1 = date1 << n; // shift left
year2 = date2 << n; // shift left

n = 16;
year1 = year1 >> n; // shift right
year2 = year2 >> n; // shift right

n = 24;
month1 = date1 >> n; // shift right
month2 = date2 >> n; // shift right

n=8;
day1 = date1 << n;  // shift left
day2 = date2 << n;  // shift left

n = 24;
day1 = day1 >> n;   // shift right
day2 = day2 >> n;   // shift right
```

But this fails in some of the tests my program has to run through, even tho i tested with a quick main and it show the correct date.

Comment: Looks like you should be using [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_&) operations to mask out the bits you need (either before or after shifting)

Comment: Given a bit pattern `abcDEFghi`, where you want to extract `DEF`, you can do it two ways: (1) use a bitmask to extract `000DEF000`, then shift it right to get `DEF`, or (2) shift it right to get `abcDEF`, then use a (slightly different) bitmask to extract `DEF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to extract everything. This will do. Assume that `dym` is an input date in the specified format.

```
uint32_t ymd = 0;
ymd |= (dym<<8)  & 0xFF000000;
ymd |= (dym<<16) & 0x00FFFF00;
ymd |= (dym>>16) & 0x000000FF;
```

Then `ymd` will be the same date but with the format year-month-day. Now you can compare them just using `>`.

Here it is in a function:

```
uint32_t dym2ymd(uint32_t, dym)
{
    uint32_t ymd = 0;
    ymd |= (dym<<8)  & 0xFF000000;
    ymd |= (dym<<16) & 0x00FFFF00;
    ymd |= (dym>>16) & 0x000000FF;
    return ymd;
}

uint32_t greater_date(uint32_t date1, uint32_t date2)
{
    return dym2ymd(date1)>dym2ymd(date2) ? date1 : date2;
}
```

I changed the types for arguments and return type. If the type needs to be able to hold 32 bits, you should not use `int`. You could have used `long` instead, but in this case it seems way more appropriate with a type that has exact width.

Comment: I ued this but the output says the following:  
 expected <185064715 0xb07dd0b>
 but was  <185064459 0xb07dc0b>

Answer (score 1):

Does the following function work for you?

```
unsigned int myd_to_ymd(unsigned int date) {
    unsigned int year = (date >> 8) & 0x000000FF;
    unsigned int month = (date >> 24) & 0x0000000F;
    unsigned int day = date & 0x0000000F;
    return year * 0x000000FF + month * 0x0000000F + day;
}

unsigned int greater_date(unsigned int date1, unsigned int date2) {
    if (myd_to_ymd(date1) >= myd_to_ymd(date2))
    {
        return date1;
    }
    else return date2;
}
```

Comment: Single letters in hex are 4 bits. Your masks are, like, too "short". You wanted to do `0x0000FFFF` `0x000000FF` etc.

Comment: @KamilCuk Corrected. Thanks